# C++ enum class to simulate Java style

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I've been working on this issue since the last 2 days and i've no clue of what's going on

I also searched on stackoverflow but i couldn't find an answer

This is an Arduino project and i'm trying to use c and c++ to write the most reusable and clean code possible

I've got these classes:

Enum.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Arduino.h>

class Enum {
    public:
        const char *name;
        uint8_t id;

        static const Enum* getValues();
        static uint8_t getSize();
        static const Enum** getValueById(uint8_t id);
        
        Enum();
        Enum(uint8_t id, const char *name);

        bool operator== (const Enum &e);
};
```

Enum.cpp

```
#include "Enum.h"

Enum::Enum() {}

Enum::Enum(uint8_t id, const char *name) {
    this->name = name;
    this->id = id;
};

bool Enum::operator== (const Enum &e)
{
   return id == e.id;
}
```

Carstatus.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Enum.h"
#include "CanbusMessageType.h"

class Carstatus : public Enum {
    public:
        static const Carstatus *EXTERNAL_TEMPERATURE;
        static const Carstatus *INTERNAL_TEMPERATURE;
        static const Carstatus *SPEED;
        static const Carstatus *INTERNAL_LUMINANCE;
        static const Carstatus *FRONT_DISTANCE;
        static const Carstatus *ENGINE_WATER_COOLING_TEMPERATURE;
        static const Carstatus *ENGINE_OIL_TEMPERATURE;
        static const Carstatus *ENGINE_INTAKE_MANIFOLD_PRESSURE;
        static const Carstatus *ENGINE_RPM;
        static const Carstatus *TRIP_DURATION;
        static const Carstatus *TRIP_AVERAGE_SPEED;
        static const Carstatus *TRIP_MAX_SPEED;

        static const Enum* getValueById(uint8_t id);
        static const Enum** getValues();
        static uint8_t getSize();

        const CanbusMessageType *type;

        Carstatus(uint8_t id, const char *name, const CanbusMessageType *type);

    private:
        static const Enum* values[];
        static uint8_t index;
};
```

Carstatus.cpp

```
#include "Carstatus.h"

Carstatus::Carstatus(uint8_t id, const char *name, const CanbusMessageType *type) : Enum(id, name) {
  this->type = type;

  values[index] = this;
  index++;
};

const Enum* Carstatus::getValueById(uint8_t id) {
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
    if(values[i]->id == id) {
      return values[i];
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

uint8_t Carstatus::getSize() {
  return Carstatus::index;
}

const Enum** Carstatus::getValues() {
  return Carstatus::values;
}

const Enum* Carstatus::values [12] = { 0 };
uint8_t Carstatus::index = 0;
const Carstatus* Carstatus::EXTERNAL_TEMPERATURE = new Carstatus(0x00, "EXTERNAL_TEMPERATURE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::INTERNAL_TEMPERATURE = new Carstatus(0x01, "INTERNAL_TEMPERATURE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::SPEED = new Carstatus(0x02, "SPEED", CanbusMessageType::INT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::INTERNAL_LUMINANCE = new Carstatus(0x03, "INTERNAL_LUMINANCE", CanbusMessageType::INT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::FRONT_DISTANCE = new Carstatus(0x04, "FRONT_DISTANCE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::ENGINE_WATER_COOLING_TEMPERATURE = new Carstatus(0x05, "ENGINE_WATER_COOLING_TEMPERATURE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::ENGINE_OIL_TEMPERATURE = new Carstatus(0x06, "ENGINE_OIL_TEMPERATURE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::ENGINE_INTAKE_MANIFOLD_PRESSURE = new Carstatus(0x07, "ENGINE_INTAKE_MANIFOLD_PRESSURE", CanbusMessageType::FLOAT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::ENGINE_RPM = new Carstatus(0x08, "ENGINE_RPM", CanbusMessageType::INT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::TRIP_DURATION = new Carstatus(0x09, "TRIP_DURATION", CanbusMessageType::STRING);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::TRIP_AVERAGE_SPEED = new Carstatus(0x0A, "TRIP_AVERAGE_SPEED", CanbusMessageType::INT);
const Carstatus* Carstatus::TRIP_MAX_SPEED = new Carstatus(0x0B, "TRIP_MAX_SPEED", CanbusMessageType::INT);
```

CanbusMessageType.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Enum.h"

class CanbusMessageType : public Enum {
    public:
        static const CanbusMessageType* INT;
        static const CanbusMessageType* FLOAT;
        static const CanbusMessageType* STRING;
        static const CanbusMessageType* BOOL;

        static const Enum* getValueById(uint8_t id);
        static const Enum** getValues();
        static uint8_t getSize();
        
        CanbusMessageType(uint8_t id, const char *name);

    private:
        static const Enum* values[];
        static uint8_t index;
};
```

CanbusMessageType.cpp

```
#include "CanbusMessageType.h"

CanbusMessageType::CanbusMessageType(uint8_t id, const char *name) : Enum(id, name) {
  values[index] = this;
  index++;
};

const Enum* CanbusMessageType::getValueById(uint8_t id) {
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
    if(values[i]->id == id) {
      return values[i];
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

uint8_t CanbusMessageType::getSize() {
  return index;
}

const Enum** CanbusMessageType::getValues() {
  return values;
}

const Enum* CanbusMessageType::values [4] = { 0 };
uint8_t CanbusMessageType::index = 0;
const CanbusMessageType* CanbusMessageType::INT = new CanbusMessageType(0x00, "INT");
const CanbusMessageType* CanbusMessageType::FLOAT = new CanbusMessageType(0x01, "FLOAT");
const CanbusMessageType* CanbusMessageType::STRING = new CanbusMessageType(0x02, "STRING");
const CanbusMessageType* CanbusMessageType::BOOL = new CanbusMessageType(0x03, "BOOL");
```

What i'm trying to achieve is a class that is emulating (somehow) java enums but I cannot understand why instantiated Carstatus objects (EXTERNAL_TEMPERATURE, INTERNAL_TEMPERATURE, ecc...) have type member equals to nullptr

I attach an online example: [text](https://wokwi.com/projects/376579352065172481)
You can found here full code: [text](https://github.com/igna09/carduino_arduino)

Someone have got some hints?
Thank you

I also tried to replace CanbusMessageType with uint8_t to store CanbusMessageType::id but it wont work

Comment: I'm not sure what is the actual question is here, but I'm 100% certain that 95% of what's shown above is utterly irrelevant and just distracting noise. Does anyone need to understand what `getValueById()` does, and how it works, for example, in order to understand the question? Obviously not. So why do you feel that it's necessary to include that, together with all the other irrelevant white noise. Before posting any questions on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here.

Comment: [Static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)

Comment: could be [initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof), in short, initializing heap allocated objects inside your `.cpp` file has undefined order, things can happen in any order, including before a global pointer gets a value.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's happening is called [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) which means any object that requires heap allocation to be initialized (and therefore non-trivial) will be initialized in any order at runtime.

the solution here is to simply avoid java's `new everything` and allocate those `CanbusMessageType` objects inside your binary, and avoid heap allocations whenever possible.

```cpp
class CanbusMessageType : public Enum {
    public:
        static const CanbusMessageType INT;
        static const CanbusMessageType FLOAT;
        static const CanbusMessageType STRING;
        static const CanbusMessageType BOOL;

        static const Enum* getValueById(uint8_t id);
        static const Enum** getValues();
        static uint8_t getSize();
        
        CanbusMessageType(uint8_t id, const char *name);

    private:
        static const Enum* values[];
        static uint8_t index;
};

const CanbusMessageType CanbusMessageType::INT = CanbusMessageType(0x00, "INT");
...
```

another way to guarantee the order of initialization of objects is to initialize them yourself at runtime, by creating any "initialization function" and have it create the objects at runtime.

Comment: Just for reference, this worked but the linker was throwing error because of breaking ODR. To solve i ad to use inline keywork `inline const CanbusMessageType CanbusMessageType::INT = CanbusMessageType(0x00, "INT");`